# Unity 2018 - UI Text Element - Not Updating Count Upon Pickup

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

My problem is that the code will only work the first item (Star Tablet) that the player touches. After that, the number will remain 1. I suspect that my Destroy() function erases the script and the count must be forgotten? However, I don't know of any alternative measures to take. 
If I'm wrong about that, please inform me of what is going wrong and what steps I'd need to fix it. Here is my entire script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class StarTabletScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameObject starTab; // The actual Star Tablet gameobject - May need to use in other script later?
    private int starTabCount = 0; // Counts total stars in the scene
    private int starTabCollected;// Star off with zero star tabs collected
    private GameObject[] starTabTotal; // Reads the total amount of star tabs in the scene
    public Image starImg; // The  star sprite
    public Text starTxt; // The star Text

    [SerializeField]
    private Renderer starMesh; // Used to deactivate the mesh of the star tab upon collision

    void Start()
    {
        starTab = GetComponent<GameObject>();
        starTabCollected = 0;
        starTabTotal = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("StarTab");

        foreach (GameObject star in starTabTotal)
        {
            starTabCount++;
        }

        StartCoroutine(StartShow()); // Shows image upon start                
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            starMesh.enabled = false;                     
            StartCoroutine(ShowStar());           
        }
    }

    IEnumerator ShowStar() // Shows star image on pickup
    {        
        starTabCollected++;
        Debug.Log("3) Stars collected "+starTabCollected);
        starImg.enabled = true;
        starTxt.enabled = true;
        starTxt.text = starTabCollected + " / " + starTabCount;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        starImg.enabled = false;
        starTxt.enabled = false;
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    IEnumerator StartShow() // Shows star on program start
    {
        Debug.Log("1) Total Stars in scene "+starTabCount);
        Debug.Log("2) StarTab.Length testing "+starTabTotal.Length);
        starImg.enabled = true;
        starTxt.enabled = true;

        starTxt.text = starTabCollected + " / " + starTabCount;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
        starImg.enabled = false;
        starTxt.enabled = false;
    }    
}
```

Comment: How is `starTxt` assigned a value?

Comment: @Draco18s starTxt.text = starTabCollected + " / " + starTabCount;

Comment: That's `starTxt.text` a member of `starTxt`

Comment: @Draco18s I have inserted the UI element text into the starTxT variable via inspector. starText.text allows me to adjust the text that's inside of starText. So I'm confused as to what you're trying to tell me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You have three copies of your script in the scene

Each copy has this:

```
private int starTabCollected;
```

This means that each one you pick up is *always the first one.*

Comment: StarTabCount works fine because it reads from the array into the scene and is a One-Time only variable. Basically, it just tells the player how many objects are in the level. The starTabCollected is the issue. Start of game the text reads: 0/20 (Assuming 20 stars were generated). I pick up the first star it reads: 1/20. However, it will never update again; it is always 1/20 and even Debug.Log() reads "1" each pickup. I'm assuming the variable isn't incrementing but once.

Comment: Ok, I kind of see what you're saying now. Each duplicate is getting the same script. This is causing the error. How do I fix this to where it will read new each time?

Comment: Same thing applies to `starTabCollected`, yes. You need to keep these values in a single, central location. Usually another script.

Comment: Well that SUCKS! lol So I need to add these to another script as a static variable and have them transferred into this script?

Comment: I moved the starTabCollected to another script as a static variable and the code works fine now. Thanks again for your help! (NOTE- Moved starTabCount to another script and it caused a major bug. Put it back in the StarTabScript and the code works perfectly)

Comment: Note that `static` is not always the solution. Yes, static lets you reference a field form anywhere, but it means there's only *one copy* of that value. In this case, its fine because you only *want* one copy.

Comment: What would be a better approach? Static is the only way that I currently know how to approach this.

Comment: You can use `GetComponent<?>()` to get a reference to a script attached to a game object.